# how to get countdown timer in DD:HH:MM:SS format in android?

Tags: android, datetime, timer, countdowntimer

hi I want to make a countdown timer in days,Hours,minutes and seconds format ,I have tried as below,But its not working,Please help me to save me,Thank you

```
long totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 86400 * 1000;

   countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                 Date date = new Date(leftTimeInMilliseconds);
                    String dateText = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
                    tv_day.setText(dateText);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
                tv_day.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Why don't you use `SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd hh:mm:ss");`?

Comment: but how to start countdown on it.Please tell me please...thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using this simple logic

```
long milliseconds = 3600000;
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
System.out.println("Sec " +seconds+ " minutes "+minutes+" hours " +hours);
```

Hope It might help you.

Comment: use this  `int days = (int) (milliseconds / (1000*60*60*24));`

Comment: I have coded as you told,countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {
   @Override
   public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
    long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;
    tv_day.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.font_bg);
    tv_day.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", (seconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)), seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60))); 

   }

Comment: No i am not getting any error..but counter gives me wrong digits.!

Comment: I guess you are not doing as i suggested. You should write ~(milisecond/1000)%60~

Comment: @suraj shukla I think your hour is days, minutes is hours and seconds is minutes. To get seconds from mili seconds, just do  `int sec = (int) (miliseconds/1000);`

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of SimpleDataFormat before starting the counter.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd hh:mm:ss");
```

And in your onTick() listener method

```
public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
    Date date = new Date(leftTimeInMilliseconds);
    String dateText = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    tv_day.setText(dateText);
}
```

Comment: thank you ,I have code as per you told,but can you please tell me what "leftmilliseconds" for 4 days..Please...brother..save me

Comment: Please see my edited code..Please...I am too close..help needed..:(

Comment: This is not correct for countdowns >365 days, because dd only shows the rest of %365

Answer (score 0):

Editing my answer an per your sample code.

What you did is fine, now instead of doing Date conversions just use `suraj shukla's` answer for conversions. (Convert leftTimeInMilliseconds and set it in your text view)

However, there is a slight mistake in his conversion formula, his hour is days, minutes is hours and seconds is minutes. To get seconds from mili seconds, just do

```
int second = (int) (leftTimeInMilliseconds /1000);
int minute = (int) ((leftTimeInMilliseconds /1000)%60);
int hour = (int) ((leftTimeInMilliseconds /1000)%(60*60));
int days = (int) ((leftTimeInMilliseconds /1000)%(60*60*24));
tv_day.setText("Remaining Time:: "+days+" Days "+hour+" Hour "+minute+" Minutes "+seconds+" Seconds");
```

Comment: Please see my edited code that I have tried please help me sir..Please